# How to limit decimal points while in a string, in python

Tags: python, set, precision

I am trying to create a code that takes a variable and inserts it into the string.
For instance.

```
x = .833333333

print("Five divided by six is {:.3}" .format(x)
```

Which turns out to be "Five divided by six is .833"

However my dificultie is when I need to insert a dollar amount and need to DECIMAL points and not two numbers.

What I have now is print

```
("Vehical 2 fuel costs -   ${:.2}" .format(veh2fuelcost))
```

However if the number is $3500 it does this $3.5e+02

Comment: `${:.2}` -> `${:.2f}`

Answer (score 2):

Try explicitly specifying the fixed type:

```
"Vehicle 2 fuel costs - ${:.2f}".format(veh2fuelcost)
```